# Registration process with a user_role table pattern

Tags: sql, database, authentication

More of a sanity check question.

I'm using a DB relation similar to this, which seems a popular pattern:
[image: Schema]

Such schema makes a registration and login process quite sophisticated. Say I want to register a user and give them a 'USER' role by default.

For registration:

1. Create a user and insert to the `users` table
2. Get the `ID` of the `USER` role from the `roles` table
3. Insert newly created user's `ID` and the fetched `ID` of the `USER` role to the `users_roles` table

For login (I want to fetch the user with their roles):

1. Authenticate user and get the `user ID` from `users` table
2. Get `Role ID`s for that user from the `user_roles` table (user may have more than one)
3. Get role names from the `roles` table

I'm guessing that you could probably do some clever `JOIN`s and nested `SELECT`s to avoid multiple statements (I'm using an SDK though, with no raw SQL option - and that means three separate DB calls) but is there a better way to do this while preserving such DB design?

Comment: use another sdk, which btw. are you using? normally all support joins and raw statements, as it would be a hassle to implement all features of a database system

Comment: @nbk I'm using a JS SDK for PocketBase (single file BaaS) - which itself is a wrapper over a REST layer for SQLite under the hood. It *kinda* allows you to write raw SQL, but you have to compile the whole PocketBase yourself

Comment: you don't need need the table roles , they can be stored in the program, and user_roles can store comma separated role_ids. If you don't need normalization. you can use a mix as described,